# Highcharts - How to draw an arrow for a specific value in a polar (wind rose) chart?

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts to draw a polar chart (like the ["wind rose" demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-wind-rose)) from a table.
Now I want to draw a marker symbol (arrow) for a specfic value (0). Because I have no "series", how can I add the marker?

Has anyone an idea how to do this in a table??

Kind regards,
Jacka

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom marker per point like:

```
series:[{
   data:[1,2,3,{
     y:0,
     marker:{
       symbol:'url(path/to/your/marker.pnh)'
     }
   }]
}]
```